# Why does state store fail with serialization issue?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka Streams 1.1.0.

I've created the following topology:

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001 (topics: [configurationTopicName])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000002
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000002 (stores: [configurationTopicName-STATE-STORE-0000000000])
      --> KTABLE-MAPVALUES-0000000003
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001
    Processor: KTABLE-MAPVALUES-0000000003 (stores: [configuration_store_application1])
      --> none
      <-- KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000002
```

The code is as follows:

```
case class Test(name: String, age: Int)
val mal: Materialized[String, Test, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]] =
  Materialized.as[String, Test, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]](configurationStoreName(applicationId))
builder.table(configurationTopicName, Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
  .someAdditionalTransformation
  .mapValues[Test](
      new ValueMapperWithKey[String, String, Test] {
         override def apply(readOnlyKey: String, value: String): Test = Test("aaa", 432)
      }, mal)
```

I'd like to build a queryable store that can be used to query it later (retrieve filtered/transformed values).

I've run a simple test using `TopologyTestDriver` and the following exception is thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kafka.streams.topology.Test cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawValue(StateSerdes.java:178)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore$1.innerValue(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:66)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore$1.innerValue(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:57)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.put(InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.java:198)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.put(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:117)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableMapValues$KTableMapValuesProcessor.process(KTableMapValues.java:103)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableMapValues$KTableMapValuesProcessor.process(KTableMapValues.java:83)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableFilter$KTableFilterProcessor.process(KTableFilter.java:89)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableFilter$KTableFilterProcessor.process(KTableFilter.java:63)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ForwardingCacheFlushListener.apply(ForwardingCacheFlushListener.java:42)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingKeyValueStore.java:101)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.access$000(CachingKeyValueStore.java:38)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore$1.apply(CachingKeyValueStore.java:83)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:142)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:100)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:127)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.flush(CachingKeyValueStore.java:123)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.flush(InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.java:267)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.flush(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:149)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:244)
>       ... 58 more

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found a reason of above exception.

I've created Materialized for storing the data, but I didn't passed any Serdes for key or value.

If you don't pass any, defaults are used. In my case it was `StringSerializer` and I was trying serialize object of `Test` class with StringSerializer ***mea culpa***

To pass Serdes `.withValueSerde(GenericSerde[Test])` only has to be added, where GenericSerdes is implementation of `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde`

```
val mal: Materialized[String, Test, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]] =
  Materialized.as[String, Test, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]](configurationStoreName(applicationId))
    .withValueSerde(GenericSerde[Test])
```